# Enable Nvidia Graphics Card

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I want to enable Nvidia, but How?
lspci, only shows the Intel Card.

```
 m-yusuf-suleman@inspiron-3543  ~  lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
```

How Do I show the Nvidia one?

lshw

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:55 memory:a9000000-a9ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:aa000000-aaffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ab000000-ab07ffff
```

Comment: Does `sudo lshw -C video` show only the same Intel card?

Comment: In your BIOS/UEFI settings, is your discrete graphics enabled?

Comment: There is no setting like that in the BIOS.  Here lshw is in the post as it could not fit here.